# SQL query slow to be executed

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with an sql query, it gives me the output that I want, and in my computer works fine, but since I have to run my db in the school's PC I get into a problem. The query needs 34! seconds to be executed, while on my pc it needs like 6.

This is my DB:

[image]

The query is: You have to find the 1 rep max( Max(Carico) ) of the exercises "Panca Orizzontale","Squat","Estensioni Bilanciere","Squat" for each user who has been gym member for more than 5 years.

This is the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT U.Nome
     , U.Cognome
     , MAX(P1.Carico) AS MaxPanca_Orizzontale
     , MAX(P2.Carico) AS MaxSquat
     , MAX(P3.Carico) AS MaxEstensioni_Bilanciere
     , MAX(P4.Carico) AS MaxLento_Avanti
  FROM utente AS U 
  left 
  join scheda AS S1 
    on U.CF=S1.ID_Utente 
  left 
  join programma AS P1 
    on S1.ID_Scheda = P1.ID_Scheda 
   AND P1.nRipetizioni = 1 
   AND P1.Esercizio = "Panca Orizzontale"
  left 
  join scheda AS S2 
    on U.CF=S2.ID_Utente 
  left 
  join programma AS P2 
    on S2.ID_Scheda = P2.ID_Scheda 
   AND P2.nRipetizioni = 1 
   AND P2.Esercizio = "Squat"
  left 
  join scheda AS S3 
    on U.CF = S3.ID_Utente 
  left 
  join programma AS P3 
    on S3.ID_Scheda = P3.ID_Scheda 
   AND P3.nRipetizioni = 1 
   AND P3.Esercizio = "Estensioni Bilanciere"
  left 
  join scheda AS S4 
    on U.CF = S4.ID_Utente 
  left 
  join programma AS P4 
    on S4.ID_Scheda = P4.ID_Scheda 
   AND P4.nRipetizioni = 1 
   AND P4.Esercizio = "Lento Avanti"
 WHERE U.CF IN(SELECT U.CF 
                 FROM utente U 
                WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year)
              )
 GROUP 
    BY U.Nome
     , U.Cognome;
```

That's the desired result:

[image]

Probably all those join are the problem, is there a way to make it faster to execute?? thanks for your time

Comment: can you provide the tablestructures and some sample data?

Comment: ... and a desired result.

Comment: added the desired result, now I try do add the create table

Comment: Proper CREATE and INSERT statements please

Answer (score 0):

I'd state that you'd better add programma.Esercizio to the group by.
Something like:

```
SELECT U.Nome, U.Cognome, P.Esercizio, MAX(Carico) AS MaxCarico
FROM utente AS U left join scheda AS S1 on U.CF=S1.ID_Utente 
left join programma AS P1 on S1.ID_Scheda=P1.ID_Scheda AND P1.nRipetizioni=1
WHERE U.CF IN(SELECT U.CF FROM utente U WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year))
GROUP BY U.Nome, U.Cognome, P.Esercizio;
```

The output would be a little different (Extra column and 4 rows instead of ne), but Its a lot better to proces for your Database server. Could you test that and see if it still fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I have now change all off my answer and wrote it new with your data.

first you must create 2 new indexe

```
ALTER TABLE programma
ADD KEY `idx_nRipetizioni` (`nRipetizioni`,`ID_Scheda`,`Esercizio`);

ALTER TABLE utente
ADD KEY `idx_ata_Iscrizione` (`Data_Iscrizione`);
```

and then you can run this. please test it the result is the same.
if you want to have NULL instead of 0 change **,0)** to **,NULL)**
in the if statement

AND see the execution time :-)

```
SELECT 
  U.Nome,
  U.Cognome,
  MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Panca Orizzontale",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxPanca_Orizzontale,
  MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Squat",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxSquat,
  MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Estensioni Bilanciere",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxEstensioni_Bilanciere,
  MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Lento Avanti",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxLento_Avanti
FROM utente AS U
LEFT JOIN scheda AS S1 ON U.CF=S1.ID_Utente
LEFT JOIN programma AS P1 ON S1.ID_Scheda=P1.ID_Scheda
          AND P1.nRipetizioni=1
WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
GROUP BY U.Nome,
         U.Cognome;
```

**sample**

**create a index**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE programma
    -> ADD KEY `idx_nRipetizioni` (`nRipetizioni`,`ID_Scheda`,`Esercizio`);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**create a index**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE utente
    -> ADD KEY `idx_ata_Iscrizione` (`Data_Iscrizione`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1
```

**run the query**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT
    ->   U.Nome,
    ->   U.Cognome,
    ->   MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Panca Orizzontale",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxPanca_Orizzontale,
    ->   MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Squat",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxSquat,
    ->   MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Estensioni Bilanciere",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxEstensioni_Bilanciere,
    ->   MAX(IF(P1.Esercizio="Lento Avanti",P1.Carico,0)) AS MaxLento_Avanti
    -> FROM utente AS U
    -> LEFT JOIN scheda AS S1 ON U.CF=S1.ID_Utente
    -> LEFT JOIN programma AS P1 ON S1.ID_Scheda=P1.ID_Scheda
    ->           AND P1.nRipetizioni=1
    -> WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
    -> GROUP BY U.Nome,
    ->          U.Cognome;
+------------+--------------+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Nome       | Cognome      | MaxPanca_Orizzontale | MaxSquat | MaxEstensioni_Bilanciere | MaxLento_Avanti |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Ajeje      | Brazov       |                  0.0 |    100.0 |                      0.0 |            35.0 |
| Aldo       | Baglio       |                 80.0 |    120.0 |                     32.5 |            50.0 |
| Fernando   | Torres       |                  0.0 |    150.0 |                      0.0 |            35.0 |
| Francesco  | Toldo        |                 90.0 |      0.0 |                     40.0 |             0.0 |
| Giovanni   | Storti       |                 65.0 |      0.0 |                      0.0 |            30.0 |
| Guendalina | Porte        |                  0.0 |     50.0 |                     20.0 |            25.0 |
| Harry      | Potter       |                150.0 |    180.0 |                     80.0 |           122.5 |
| John       | Cena         |                135.0 |    240.0 |                     60.0 |            75.5 |
| Kevin      | Velociraptor |                  0.0 |      0.0 |                     20.0 |            95.0 |
| Luciano    | Spalletti    |                 60.0 |    280.0 |                     95.0 |           100.0 |
| Marcella   | Mandria      |                  0.0 |     50.0 |                      0.0 |            27.5 |
| Marcelo    | Zalayeta     |                140.0 |    200.0 |                     55.0 |            60.0 |
| Radja      | Nainggolan   |                 90.0 |    120.0 |                      0.0 |            40.0 |
| Romina     | Power        |                  0.0 |      0.0 |                    140.0 |            20.0 |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it shows me an error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @LucaPearl - now the errors corrected in my answer. please check again. i have no data

Comment: nope it doesn't work, this is what it shows https://i.gyazo.com/43316678aac5c90bd302f2d5f83d0c7c.png

Comment: I'm adding the db population on the op

Comment: @LucaPearl - if have change my answer again. i have rewrite the query and it look good. the result is the same in a test. i hope it works now for you. the execution time is much faster

Comment: Thank you, today I'll try it on my school pc